# Stopping GroupLayout components from stretching vertically

Tags: swing, grouplayout

Is there an easy way to get all (or most) of the components in a GroupLayout application NOT stretch vertically?  I know I can do it by forcing each component to it's preferred size when I add it, but that makes the code so much more verbose:

```
       .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
          .addComponent(oDevRadio)
          .addComponent(oInstRadio)
       )
```

Becomes

```
       .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
          .addComponent(oDevRadio,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
          .addComponent(oInstRadio,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                        GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
       )
```

Is there a way to set it as a default, and just specify the elements I *want* to be stretchable?

**References**
- [addComponent's spec](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.ParallelGroup.html#addComponent(java.awt.Component))

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the only method of telling GroupLayout components not to stretch or otherwise be misaligned requires that the relevant components be inside a ParallelGroup. It is then a simple matter to set the resizeable flag of the ParallelGroup to false.

[Javadoc of ParallelGroup creator with relevant flag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html#createParallelGroup%28javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment,%20boolean%29)

For example, in the following code jspCasts is a very tall component. Without a new ParallelGroup with the flag being set to false, components next to it would either stretch or not align neatly as they should.

```
vGroup.addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING).
    addComponent(jspCasts).
    addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(Alignment.CENTER, false).
      // without worrying about vertical stretching or misalignment, 
      // add your components here
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. I've handled it with a utility class:

```
package alpha;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Group;

public class GroupLayoutUtil
{
    public static GroupLayout.Group addPreferred(Group g, Component c)
    {
        return g.addComponent(c, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 
                GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE);
    }
}
```